# A corollary of Schur's lemma in positive characteristic

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, positive-characteristic

A corollary of Schur's lemma reads ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Schur%27s+lemma)):

> In the case that the ground field is an algebraically closed field of
>   characteristic zero; endomorphisms $\psi:V \rightarrow V$ of a finite dimensional
>   irreducible representations V are a multiple $c \cdot \textrm{Id}$ of the identity
>   operator.

The proof given in section 3 of the nLab page does not explicitly state that it uses the characteristic being zero.

1. Where does the proof fail when the ground field is algebraically closed but of positive characteristic?
2. What are some positive characteristic counter-examples?
3. Is there a weaker form that works in positive characteristic?

Comment: Good point, as far as I can tell, the same proof works in characteristic $p$.  I tried some google searches and for example found these notes http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf where Corollary 1.17 seems to be the same result with no mention of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly well in arbitrary characteristic, with the same proof : over an algebraically closed field, in finite dimension, $\psi$ has an eigenvalue $c$ thus $\ker(\psi-c.id)\neq 0$ is a subrepresentation, therefore it is the whole of $V$, so $\psi = c.id$